# Search in build results window - Sublime Text 3

Tags: search, find, sublime-text-3

When the Build Results panel is open, I frequently want to search in it. The only solution I've  found so far is to copy all contents, open a new tab, paste contents, then do a find. Is there any way to search the panel contents directly?